# Explicit reference loading in Entity Framework on a deleted entity doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a callback that applies logic to entities before they are saved.

Update:
This is an intentional breaking change between 6 and 7:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#deleted-fixup

It seems to be working when an entity is added or modified.

But if an entity is deleted - then `dbContext.Entry(obj).Reference(p=>p.Child).Load()` doesn't seem to be working, even though I can see the child object data is being loaded from the database (I can see SQL query being executed and child's data comes back from the database).

Is Reference(...).Load() work differently for a deleted entity?

How can I use Reference(...).Load() with a deleted entry?

Entity Framework Core 7 / .NET 6 Core

A minimum working example follows.

Here is where it fails:

```
dbContext.Remove(company);

// Trying to load Vendor after company is marked for deletion does not load vendor.
dbContext.Entry(company).Reference(c => c.Vendor).Load();

// Fails here :(
Assert(company.Vendor is not null);
```

Look for `SendNotificationToVendor` to see a demo of the use case I'm trying to make work.

```
// .NET Core 6
// Entity Framework 7

/*
Here is my csproj

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>10</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

*/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    private const string _connectionString =
        "username=app;password=@9@he@fxpjIh&UPYJU54;host=database-1.ctwewift55dc.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;port=5432;database=postgres";

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString);
    }

    public MyDbContext() {
        SavingChanges += (sender, _) => {
            var dbContext = (DbContext) sender!;
            var deletedCompanies = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(ce => ce.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                .Where(ce => ce.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Company))
                .Select(ce => ce.Entity)
                .Cast<Company>();
            foreach (var company in deletedCompanies) {
                if (company.Vendor is null) {
                    dbContext.Entry(company).Reference(c => c.Vendor).Load();
                }

                SendNotificationToVendor(company, company.Vendor!);
            }
        };
    }

    private void SendNotificationToVendor(Company company, Vendor vendor) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {vendor.Name}. Company {company.Name} has been removed from the system.");
    }

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Vendor {
    public Vendor() {
        Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Company {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Vendor? Vendor { get; set; } = null!;
}

internal class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        CreateTestObjects();

        var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
        var company = dbContext.Companies.First();

        Assert(company.Vendor is null);

        dbContext.Remove(company);

        // Trying to load Vendor after company is marked for deletion does not load vendor.
        dbContext.Entry(company).Reference(c => c.Vendor).Load();

        // Fails here :(
        Assert(company.Vendor is not null);

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    private static void Assert(bool condition) {
        if (!condition) {
            throw new Exception("Assertion failed.");
        }
    }

    private static void CreateTestObjects() {
        var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
        var vendor = dbContext.Vendors.FirstOrDefault();
        if (vendor is null) {
            vendor = new Vendor {
                Name = "Vend-1"
            };
            dbContext.Vendors.Add(vendor);
        }

        var company = dbContext.Companies.Include(c => c.Vendor).FirstOrDefault();
        if (company is null) {
            company = new Company {
                Name = "Comp-1"
            };
            dbContext.Companies.Add(company);
        }

        company.Vendor ??= vendor;

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        dbContext.Database.CloseConnection();
        dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to be working, even though I can see the object loading"? Is it loading or not? And why do you want to load related entities from an entity that doesn't exist anymore (or is scheduled to be deleted)?

Comment: @Progman, 1) I stepped through the code and I can see that code that loads the dependent entity (p.Child) is being executed, and the data for that entity comes back from the database, put `p.Child` stays null. 2) as to why, I have code that is executed on every database mutation and executes custom logic. In this case if parent entity is deleted, I need to find every child that is referenced by that parent and send an email notification "Entity P that used to reference entity Child 'XYZ' has been deleted." Note that in this case Child is not owned by the parent, so Child is not being deleted.

Comment: I checked it real quick and could use `Reference().Load()` even on deleted entities, but it is was only a small test program. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows the problem you have with `Reference().Load()` on deleted entities.

Comment: Your edit does not include a MCVE, which can be compiled and tested by others. But when "company" is in the state "deleted", you can still use `Reference().Load()` to load the navigation entity. When the entity is however in the state "detached", you will get an `InvalidOperationException` with a message like "The navigation 'Company.Vendor' cannot be loaded because the entity is not being tracked. Navigations can only be loaded for tracked entities."

Comment: @Progman I've been trying to make my code work in .NET Fiddle (alas, failed). I do not get `InvalidOperationException`. It executes Load `code` fine, but `company.Vendor` remains null. Running same `Reference...Load` one step before the company is removed (with `dbContext.Remove(company);`) works as expected. I can share complete .sln zip, but not sure whats a proper way to do so on SO.

Comment: Updated the question. Very confused. I tried similar code on two boxes (both are windows). Tried it with .net 6 and 7, C# 10 and 11, and `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` 7.0.* and 8-preview. I get the same result every time. Do you mind sharing your solution? (I'm using Rider IDE, can't imagine that being a problem).

Comment: Ha! Works with Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 6.0.8... but not with >= 7.0.0

Comment: I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0` with `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0`, I don't have PostgreSQL. Please edit your question to emphasize that your code works with `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 6.0.8`, but not with `7.0.0`. This sounds like a bug, but it can also be an intentionally change by design. However, a quick glance at the changelog doesn't show that...

Comment: Filed an issue with efcore: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30406

Comment: This is an intentional breaking change: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#deleted-fixup

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.  Since EF 7 refuses to set the loaded entity instances if the ReferenceEntry is deleted, the work-around I found was to just tell EF that it's not deleted before calling Load().  So in your example, something like this should work:

```
// Trying to load Vendor after company is marked for deletion does not load vendor.
var refEntry = dbContext.Entry(company).Reference(c => c.Vendor);
if (refEntry.EntityEntry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
{
    refEntry.EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    refEntry.Load(); 
    refEntry.EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
else
    refEntry.Load();
```