# EF Core detect child changes on parent at SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core Web API. When the entity a user is viewing is changed, the client needs to be notified to update their data.

For this, I need to detect when a change is made to a specific parent entity. I did this by checking if the `Entry(Parent).State` is set to anything but unchanged in an override of the context's `SaveChanges` method:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach(var p in Parents)
    {
        if (Entry(p).State != EntityState.Unchanged)
        {
            // Notify client
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges()
}
```

My issue is that if any of the child objects are changed I also need to tell the client to update, but I can't seem to find a way to detect this.

The `Entry`'s properties (`Entry().Properties`, `.Navigations`, etc.) all show the children as `IsModified == false` and the change tracker doesn't seem to help either.

Edit: I could check the change tracker's `Entries` and see if the id of the `Parent` I'm looking for is set as the modified child's foreign key, but I need to also be able to detect if a child of a child is changed. If anything related to the `Parent` changes, the client needs to update its view.

**Edit 2 - Answer:** After working on the project some more it turns out my previous answer (removed in this edit) and the answers given so far don't work with deletion of child entities.

On setting an entity's state to deleted or marking them for deletion using `_context.DbSet<>.Remove()`, their relations aren't loaded anymore on calling `EntityEntry.Load()`. This is an [intended breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes?tabs=v7#deleted-fixup) from EF Core 6 to 7. As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75561989/explicit-reference-loading-in-entity-framework-on-a-deleted-entity-doesnt-seem), I went with the solution of temporarily setting the entry state to `Modified`, checking for the affected parent entity and then returning the entry's state to `Deleted`. This isn't perfect but it's the only way I could find.

This solution also differs from the ones in the answers here in that I changed the approach to start at only the changed entities and search for the nearest `Parent` rather than my initial approach of checking every `Parent` and all their children.

Here is the code:

```
public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    DetectAndNotifyChanges();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

private void DetectAndNotifyChanges()
{
    List<EntityEntry> changedEntries = new List<EntityEntry>();
    foreach (var entity in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
    {
        changedEntries.Add(entity);
    }

    foreach(var entry in changedEntries)
    {
        bool deleted = false;
        if(entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            deleted = true;
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        int changedParentId = RecursiveSearch(entry);
        if(changedParentId != -1)
        {
            //Notify client
        }

        if(deleted)
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
    }
}

private List<dynamic> checkedEntries = new List<dynamic>();

private int RecursiveSearch(dynamic entry)
{
    if (entry.Entity.GetType().BaseType == Parents.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0])
    {
        return entry.Entity.Id;
    }

    foreach (var navigationEntry in entry.Navigations)
    {
        if(navigationEntry is CollectionEntry collectionEntry)
        {
            collectionEntry.Load();
            foreach(var referencedEntity in collectionEntry.CurrentValue)
            {
                var referencedEntry = Entry(referencedEntity);

                if (!checkedEntries.Contains(referencedEntry))
                {
                    checkedEntries.Add(referencedEntry);
                    return RecursiveSearch(referencedEntry);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (navigationEntry is ReferenceEntry referenceEntry)
        {
            referenceEntry.Load();
            dynamic referencedEntry = referenceEntry.TargetEntry;

            if(referencedEntry != null)
            {
                if (!checkedEntries.Any(x => x.Entity.GetType() == referencedEntry.Entity.GetType() && x.Entity.Id == referencedEntry.Entity.Id))
                {
                    checkedEntries.Add(referencedEntry);
                    return RecursiveSearch(referencedEntry);
                }
            }

            
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: there is a method that allows you to detect changes on the changetracker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection

Comment: @jeb I tried that, but it just shows the child objects as modified, the parent still as unchanged. I suppose that would be enough if I checked the Parent FK property but i also need to know if a child of a child of a parent is changed, essentially if anything about a parent's details is different. I'll edit the question to include this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
{
    DetectAndNotifyChanges();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

private void DetectAndNotifyChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            if (entry.Entity is Parent parent)
            {
                if (HasChangesInChildren(parent))
                {
                    // Notify client about changes in parent or children
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private bool HasChangesInChildren(Parent parent)
{
    foreach (var navigationEntry in Entry(parent).Navigations)
    {
        if (navigationEntry is CollectionEntry collectionEntry)
        {
            foreach (var child in collectionEntry.CurrentValue)
            {
                var childEntry = Entry(child);
                if (childEntry.State != EntityState.Unchanged || HasChangesInChildren(child))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (navigationEntry is ReferenceEntry referenceEntry)
        {
            var childEntry = referenceEntry.TargetEntry;
            if (childEntry.State != EntityState.Unchanged || HasChangesInChildren(childEntry.Entity as Parent))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Recursively traverse child entities and for each entity check its EntityState and mark the parent entity as modified if any child entity has changes.

Answer (score 0):

To detect changes of an entity without getting a `StackOverflowException` you need to exclude checking the children pointing back again to their parent.

The following code is an extension method on `DbContext` but can of course also be changed to override in `SaveChanges` directly:

```
/// <summary>Whether the entity itself or any of its children have been changed.</summary>
public static bool IsChanged<T>(this DbContext dbContext, T entity) where T : class
{
    return IsChanged(dbContext, entity, null);
}

private static bool IsChanged<T>(DbContext dbContext, T entity, T? parent) where T : class
{
    bool IsChangedEntry(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        return entry.State != EntityState.Unchanged || IsChanged(dbContext, entry.Entity, entity);
    }

    var entityEntry = dbContext.Entry(entity);
    if (entityEntry.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
    {
        return true;
    }

    IEnumerable<EntityEntry> collectionEntries = entityEntry.Navigations
        .OfType<CollectionEntry>()
        .Where(entry => entry.CurrentValue != null)
        .SelectMany(entry => entry.CurrentValue!.Cast<object?>())
        .Where(collectionObject => collectionObject != null)
        .Select(dbContext.Entry!)
        .Where(entry => entry.Entity != parent);

    IEnumerable<EntityEntry> referenceEntries = entityEntry.References
        .Select(entry => entry.TargetEntry)
        .Where(entry => entry != null)
        .Where(entry => entry!.Entity != parent)!;

    return collectionEntries.Concat(referenceEntries).Any(IsChangedEntry);
}
```